# Ember Two-Level Navigation active-CSS link-to not working

Tags: css, ember.js, navigation, routes, nested

after reading a lot about the new nested routs in ember my transitions work and the outlets are replaced. Sadly there is still a problem: I have a two-level-navigation --> Main-Navigation and Sidebar. All links are generated with {{link-to}}. If I click on a subitem in  the sidebar the item doesn't get the "active" CSS-Class in Chrome (Firefox works). If i click the same link in the main Navigation the link in the sidebar don't get activated.

Here you can see my problem under "Users" --> http://jsbin.com/omAZiZe/1/edit
(you need to see the normal desktop version of the navigation to see the sidebar)
"Users" and "User Übersicht" have  identical links but only one is active. Also there is a Browser Problem in Firefox and Opera subitems in the sidebar get active. In Chrome this dosen't work. How can I solve this problem?

Here my Version:

```
Ember      : 1.1.3+pre.5a35fc76
Ember Data : 1.0.0-beta.4+canary.c15b8f80
Handlebars : 1.0.0
jQuery     : 1.10.2
```

and my Code:

Application:

```
    App.Router.map(function(){
    this.resource("users",function() {
        this.route("user", {path: "users/:user_id"});
        this.route("new");
    });

    App.UsersIndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    renderTemplate: function() {
        this.render("sidebar", {into: 'application' , outlet: "sidebar",  controller: "users.index"  });
        this.render("userslist", {outlet: "users", controller: "users.index"});
    },
    model: function() {
        return users;
    }
    });

    App.UsersUserRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    renderTemplate: function() {
        this.render("sidebar", {into: 'application' , outlet: "sidebar",  controller: "users.index"  });
        this.render("users/user", {outlet: "users", controller: "user"});
    },
    model: function() {
         return users[0];
    }
    });

    App.UsersNewRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    renderTemplate: function() {
        this.render("sidebar", {into: 'application' , outlet: "sidebar",  controller: "users.index"  });
        this.render("users/new", {outlet: "users", controller: "users"});
    },
    model: function() {

    }
    });
//spezieller Array Controller
App.UsersIndexController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
     navigation: [
               {controller: "users.index", text: "User Übersicht" , hint: "Alle User als Liste", icon: "glyphicon glyphicon-user"},
               {controller: "users.new", text: "Neuen User anlegen" , hint: "Hier können neue User angelegt werden", icon: "glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign"}
              ] 
});
```

Index.html

```
 <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name ="users">
        {{outlet users}}
    </script>

    <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name ="userslist">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-lg-12">
            <h1>Users</h1>

                    <table class="table table-hover">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Id</th>
                                <th>Username</th>
                                <th>Vorname</th>
                                <th>Nachname</th>
                                <th>E-Mail</th>
                                <th>Rolle</th>
                                <th></th>
                            </tr>
                        <thead>
                        <tbody>
                             {{#each}}
                             <tr>
                                <td>{{id}}</td>
                                <td>{{username}}</td>
                                <td>{{prename}}</td>
                                <td>{{surname}}</td>
                                <td>{{email}}</td>
                                <td>{{role}}</td>
                                <td> {{#link-to "users.user" this }}<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span>{{/link-to}} <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span></td>
                            </tr>
                           {{/each}}

                        </tbody>
                    </table>      
                    {{outlet}}  
          </div>
        </div><!-- /.row -->
    </script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="users/user">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-12">
        <h1>User <small>{{username}}</small></h1>
            {{email}}

      </div>
    </div><!-- /.row -->
</script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="sidebar">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav side-nav">
    {{#each item in navigation}}
        <li> 
            {{#link-to item.controller}}
                {{#if item.icon}}
                    <span {{bind-attr class="item.icon"}} ></span>
                {{/if}}
                {{item.text}}
            {{/link-to}}
        </li>
    {{/each}}
    </ul> 
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your initial problem in truth is with css. Your sidebar receive the `active` class but your ui don't change.

If you add the following you will see the sidebar item with the background color black, when active:

```
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>li>a.active {
  background-color: #080808;
}
```

After this you will note that clicking in `Neuen User anlegen` item, both `Neuen User anlegen` and `User Übersicht` will have the active class and both will have the background black. This is the expected behavior, because the `Neuen User anlegen` link have the `link-to "users"`, so when you click in `Neuen User anlegen` you go to "users.new" route, and if you are in the "users.new" route, you also are in "users" route. So just change the `link-to "users"` to `link-to "users.index"`, in your `UsersIndexController`:

```
App.UsersIndexController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
     navigation: [
         {controller: "users.index", text: "User Übersicht" , hint: "Alle User als Liste", icon: "glyphicon glyphicon-user", },
         {controller: "users.new", text: "Neuen User anlegen" , hint: "Hier können neue User angelegt werden", icon: "glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign"}
     ] 
});
```

This is the updated jsbin with this working http://jsbin.com/omAZiZe/4/edit

Comment: Works great... thanks. How du you debug this things? Handelbars make it hard to debug that stuff...

Comment: You are welcome. I looked the link tag in the inspector, and the class `active` was present, but no matched css rules found for background-color. So I added one.

Answer (score 2):

A solution for this scenario is using the `currentWhen` parameter on the `link-to` helper. If that parameter is used, Ember compares the currently active `route` names, not to the link-to’s `route` name argument, but to it's `currentWhen` parameter. If there is a match the link is considered active.

The explained above would in practice look like this:

```
{{#link-to "users.new" this currentWhen="users"}}New{{/link-to}}
{{#link-to "users.edit" this currentWhen="users"}}Edit{{/link-to}}
...
```

In the example the `users` route will be considered active on the sub-routes `users.new`, `users.edit` and so on.

Hope it helps.